# Webview Progress Dialog NPObject Error - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, android-webview

if i call onclick="showLoader();" on my webview site,
i get this onclick error in my log

Android Studio log:
"Error calling method on NPObject."

anyone who knows something about this Dialog webview error?

I would be very grateful

Best Regards

Dialog:

```js
public class ProgressDialogHelper {
    private static ProgressDialog progress;

    public static void dismissProgress() {
        if (progress != null) {
            progress.dismiss();
            progress.cancel();
            progress = null;
        }
    }

    public static void showProgress(Context mContext) {
        if (progress != null) {
            return;
        }
        progress = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        progress.setView(View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.progress_bar_layout, null));
        progress.setMessage(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.loading));
        progress.show();
    }
}
```

Activity:

```js
 @JavascriptInterface
    public void showLoader() {
        ProgressDialogHelper.showProgress(mContext);
    }

 @JavascriptInterface
     public void hideLoader() {
         ProgressDialogHelper.dismissProgress();
   }
```

This solution dont works for me:

```js
 @JavascriptInterface
public void showLoader() {
    ((MainActivity) mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ProgressDialogHelper.showProgress(mContext);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are getting this error, but ProgressDialog is deprecated since api 26. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog

My recommendation is to use ProgressBar embedded in your UI as the documentation says and if you need to block the UI use:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

Just make sure to clear the flag once the ProgressBar is hiding.